# How to use/re-use custom complex css (like webkit-keyframes mover) in blazor?

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor

I am trying to implement css styles in sample application.

I'm using blazor in an application, but found some problem with UI designing.

I created a simple Employee form with bootstrap. Now i want to create some styles and then re-use it. This is the actual css which needs to be implemented.

```
.register {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3931af, #00c6ff);
    margin-top: 3%;
    padding: 3%;
}

.register-left {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 4%;
}

.register-left input {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 60%;
    background: #f8f9fa;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #383d41;
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.register-right {
    background: #f8f9fa;
    border-top-left-radius: 10% 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10% 50%;
}

.register-left img {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 25%;
    -webkit-animation: mover 2s infinite alternate;
    animation: mover 1s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mover {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}

@keyframes mover {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
}

.register-left p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 12%;
    margin-top: -9%;
}

.register .register-form {
    padding: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.btnRegister {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2%;
    background: #0062cc;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.register .nav-tabs {
    margin-top: 3%;
    border: none;
    background: #0062cc;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    width: 28%;
    float: right;
}

.register .nav-tabs .nav-link {
    padding: 2%;
    height: 34px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 1.5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.register .nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
    border: none;
}

.register .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    width: 100px;
    color: #0062cc;
    border: 2px solid #0062cc;
    border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.register-heading {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-bottom: -15%;
    color: #495057;
}

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">


<div class="container">
<br>  <p class="text-center">More bootstrap 4 components on <a href="http://bootstrap-ecommerce.com/"> Bootstrap-ecommerce.com</a></p>
<hr>





<div class="card bg-light">
<article class="card-body mx-auto" style="max-width: 400px;">
    <h4 class="card-title mt-3 text-center">Create Account</h4>
    <p class="text-center">Get started with your free account</p>
    <p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-twitter"> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>   Login via Twitter</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-facebook"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>   Login via facebook</a>
    </p>
    <p class="divider-text">
        <span class="bg-light">OR</span>
    </p>
    <form>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
         </div>
        <input name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" type="text">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
         </div>
        <input name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" type="email">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select" style="max-width: 120px;">
            <option selected="">+971</option>
            <option value="1">+972</option>
            <option value="2">+198</option>
            <option value="3">+701</option>
        </select>
        <input name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" type="text">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-building"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option selected=""> Select job type</option>
            <option>Designer</option>
            <option>Manager</option>
            <option>Accaunting</option>
        </select>
    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Create password" type="password">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->                                      
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Create Account  </button>
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->      
    <p class="text-center">Have an account? <a href="">Log In</a> </p>                                                                 
</form>
</article>
</div> <!-- card.// -->

</div> 
<!--container end.//-->

<br><br>
<article class="bg-secondary mb-3">  
<div class="card-body text-center">
    <h3 class="text-white mt-3">Bootstrap 4 UI KIT</h3>
<p class="h5 text-white">Components and templates  <br> for Ecommerce, marketplace, booking websites 
and product landing pages</p>   <br>
<p><a class="btn btn-warning" target="_blank" href="http://bootstrap-ecommerce.com/"> Bootstrap-ecommerce.com  
 <i class="fa fa-window-restore "></i></a></p>
</div>
<br><br>
</article>
```

The

```
         <Styled @bind-Classname="@register">
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3931af, #00c6ff);
                margin-top: 3%;
                padding: 3%;
            </Styled>
  <div class="container @register">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 @register-left">
                </div>
           </div>
  </div>

      @code {
         private string register;
    }
```

line reports a problem and I have no idea with it since I'm a newbie with blazor. What should I do in my code?

Application built with asp. Net core 3.0", "blazor preview 9".

Output: I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve the issue.

I am getting the following exception:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>           Error
>   The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.    EMS.Client  C:\S\S\Client\Pages\AddEm.razor 6

Comment: why do you need @register as the variable is not set to anything  why not just class="register" or is you do want programatically  change the class use class="@variableWithClassName"

Comment: Hi David,  I want to use css styles in blazor razor page. I think I have no option except keeping the css styles in variables and then using it with html elements.  Can anyone suggest me?  How ll I use key-frames or other complex css styles?